# Is it possible for str.encode(encoding='utf-8', errors='strict') to raise UnicodeError?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-unicode

I am writing some code that needs to work with both Py2.7 and Py3.7+.

I need to write text to a file using UTF-8 encoding.  My code looks like this:

```
import six
...
content = ...
if isinstance(content, six.string_types):
    content = content.encode(encoding='utf-8', errors='strict')

# write 'content' to file
```

Above, is it possible for `content.encode()` to raise `UnicodeError` from either Py2.7 or Py3.7+?  I cannot think of a scenario where this is possible.  I am not a Python expert, so I think there there must be an edge case.

Here is my reasoning why I think it will never raise `UnicodeError`:

- `six.string_types` covers three types: Py2.7 `str` & `unicode`, Py3.7+ `str`
- All of these types can *always* encode as UTF-8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible:

```
import six

content = ''.join(map(chr, range(0x110000)))
if isinstance(content, six.string_types):
    content = content.encode(encoding='utf-8', errors='strict')
```

Result ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY3BCsIwEETv@YrckkAtFS8i9FukxG27Qjdhd5X262MqFecyAzP7Nm86J7qUgktOrFY2MZmR1NfUvoEFEwVjfjWuxsRECqS2t861z4TklyH7OHNjeaAJfLeez11VCMHgaFGQRAeK4I/TZge1ovXRdNctg4SbsVV/9JFaoJge4L9W17176Xi6usYCc2Lp3U6J6kIpHw), using Python 3.7.4):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".code.tio", line 5, in <module>
    content = content.encode(encoding='utf-8', errors='strict')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode characters in position 55296-57343: surrogates not allowed
```

And `UnicodeEncodeError`s are `UnicodeError`s.

Comment: This is a brilliant idea!  I confirm it fails as you say from Py3.7+.  However, this code `''.join(map(chr, range(0x110000)))` throws a `ValueError` from Py2.7.  Following your idea: Is there a way to manufacture an invalid string in Py2.7?

Comment: @kevinarpe For Python 2, use `unichr`. But then that [works without error](https://tio.run/##RY3BCoMwEETv@YrckoAN2lMp@C1F0lW34CZs1qJfn8Zi6VxmYGbfpl3mSNdScEmRRec9q8RIYmvyb@CMkZxSvxo3pUIkARLd69UY/4pIdhmSXQnDzI3mgSaw7dZ1bZVzTuGoMSNlGSiAPc@bA@az1GfTQ/YE2d2Vrvrjz@SBQnyC/Vpd92aV8XIzjQbmyLk3ByWIcaV8AA), at least on that system with that version (and maybe there's some configuration that could affect this).

Comment: Great follow-up!  I confirm `six.unichr` can generate an invalid UTF-8 string using the correct build on Py2.7.  (My Py2.7 gives this error: `ValueError: unichr() arg not in range(0x10000) (narrow Python build)` ... but ignore that if you have a wide Python build.)

Comment: @kevinarpe Not sure what you mean. `six.unichr` generates a Unicode string, not a UTF-8 string. And you say it *can* generate one but then say you get that `ValueError`. But the "narrow build" at least shows that there is indeed *some* configuration, so not getting an error with a particular configuration wouldn't prove it can't happen.